# Получить ID подкатегории в цикле Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Приветствую,

подскажите, как получить ID подкатегории не учитывая родительскую категорию.

Использую `$wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;` но выводит ID первой, родительской категории

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <li class="<?php echo $wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id; ?> "><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Comment: Оформите свой комментарий ответом на вопрос, чтобы при возникновении подобного вопроса у других, они быстро смогли найти на него ответ

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'product_cat' );
if( $terms && ! is_wp_error($terms) ){
      foreach( $terms as $term ){
           if ( $term->parent ) { 
                        echo $term->term_id; 
           }
      }
}
```